# AG-Grid - Apply Style to Whole Column Dynamically?

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-ng2

I need to apply a background color to a whole column when a custom editor is opened on a cell. I am using:

```
const col = this.params.column.getColDef();
col.cellStyle = { 'background-color': 'yellow' };
```

But this is only affecting the cell currently being edited, and not the whole column, which is what I need. I'm using Angular 4+

Answer (score 1):

You need to add this to your colDef for the column, as opposed to setting it dynamically, note that this property can also be a callback so you can dynamically adjust your styling.

https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-cell-styles/

https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-cell-editing/#editing-api